# check if an image broken

Tags: php, jquery, html, image

I am testing an image hosting script but there is one issue,when I drag and drop the image to my webpage, it's uploading, but when I hit the F5/refresh button the unfinished image is hosted to my folder,how can I check if an image is broken using php or send a jquery (XHR) request to the php file to stop the upload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("img")
  .error(function(){
   alert('error loading image');
  })
  .attr("src", "missing.png");//fallback image
```

with php you can actually save filesize() in database(during upload) and checking it with size of file in folder(before u display) will give great help.

Comment: This error will only fire if "missing.png" is not found, right?

Comment: @david ya nope for that we need another....:) actually actually saving filesize() in database and checking it with file in folder will give great help??